# How to use toggleClass on multiple elements but not at the same time

Tags: javascript, jquery

so the problem I have is quite simple.
I have a span `<span class=""spDetails>Show More</span>` and with this element I am expanding a section to show more text.

The problem I have is that I want to use this function in other sections of the page.

This is the jquery code which I am using to toggleClass active.

```
$(".spDetails").click(function() {
  $(".divFees").toggleClass("feesActive");
});
```

My question is: I don't want to write this line of code for every element using this toggle, is there a way to create this for multiple elements with different class names or IDs? Thanks.

Right, so here is my HTML: (shortened version!)

```
<div id="optionOne" class="elementOne">
     <div class="divFees">
         <p>Text Text</p>
     </div>
     <span class="showMore">Show More</span>
</div>

<div id="optionTwo" class="elementTwo">
     <div class="divFees">
         <p>Text Text</p>
     </div>
     <span class="showMore">Show More</span>
</div>
```

I m trying to hide and display `<div class="divFees"></div>` only when there child  `<span>` is clicked.

Comment: Show us your html, so we can get a better understanding of your problem

Comment: Also your span is invalid, you class is outside the `""` `class=""spDetails`

Comment: Does this all happen `.spDetails` click ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the toggleable section comes after the toggling `span` :

```js
$(".spDetails").on("click", function(e) {
  
  $(this).next().toggleClass("active");
  
});
```

```css
[id*='div'] {
  height: 60px;
  background: #f2f2f2;
  border: #f6f6f6;
}

.active {
  background: #555555;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section>

<span class="spDetails" data-toggle="#div1">Toggle 1</span>
<div id="div1"></div>

<span class="spDetails" data-toggle="#div2">Toggle 2</span>
<div id="div2"></div>


</section>
```

Or with extra attributes to specify the target:

```js
$(".spDetails").on("click", function(e) {
  
  var target = $($(this).data("toggle"));
  target.toggleClass("active");
  
});
```

```css
[id*='div'] {
  height: 60px;
  background: #f2f2f2;
  border: #f6f6f6;
}

.active {
  background: #555555;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section>

<span class="spDetails" data-toggle="#div1">Toggle 1</span>
<div id="div1"></div>

<span class="spDetails" data-toggle="#div2">Toggle 2</span>
<div id="div2"></div>


</section>
```

Comment: I've used the second option of your answer and it worked like a charm, thank you very much!

Comment: Always happy to help :)

Answer (score 1):

You can just append your desired elements in the selector using `,`.

```
$(".divFees , .otherOnes , #otherOneWithId").toggleClass("feesActive");
```

Answer (score 0):

I imagine two ways:

Easy way:

Make function with args for your event. Example:

```
function setToogleClass(button, toggleElement, toggleClass) {
  $('.' + button).click(function() {
    $('.' + toggleElement).toggleClass(toggleClass);
  });
}
setToggleClass("spDetails", "divFees", "feesActive")
```

Hard way:

Set event function by all classes who has className and who found child or parent or current elements.

```
function initToggleEvents() {
  var toggleButtons = $('toggle-button');
  var activeClassName = 'toggle-active';
  toggleButtons.forEach(function(toggleButton) {
    toggleButton.click(function(event) {
      // if event.target has parentNode that toggleClass(activeClassName)
      // else another rules
    }
  }
}
```